# Python dataframe assign values based on another column with condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, date

Have a df with columns date , name and number. trying to tag same name records if there count >3. And should tag status as old_employee to the oldest dates.

```
date                            name      number 

2021-05-06T07:35:03.000Z        mark       123
2021-04-06T07:35:03.000Z        mark       123
2021-03-03T07:35:03.000Z        mark       123
2021-02-03T07:35:03.000Z        mark       123

2021-05-06T07:35:03.000Z        tom       4123
2021-04-06T07:35:03.000Z        tom       4123
2021-03-03T07:35:03.000Z        tom       4123

2021-02-06T07:35:03.000Z        john       512


2021-02-06T07:35:03.000Z        wood       512
2021-02-06T07:35:03.000Z        wood       512


2020-05-06T07:35:03.000Z        paul       723
2020-04-06T07:35:03.000Z        paul       723
2020-03-03T07:35:03.000Z        paul       723
2020-02-03T07:35:03.000Z        paul       723
2020-02-03T05:35:03.000Z        paul       723
2020-02-02T07:35:03.000Z        paul       723
2020-02-01T07:35:03.000Z        paul       723

2020-05-06T07:35:03.000Z        tomy       623
2020-04-06T07:35:03.000Z        tomy       623
2020-03-03T07:35:03.000Z        tomy       623
2020-02-03T07:35:03.000Z        tomy       623        
2020-02-03T05:35:03.000Z        tomy       623        
2020-02-02T07:35:03.000Z        tomy       623
```

If Same Name record is there more than 3 times we have to tag record with oldest date as old_employee.

expected output :

```
date                            name      number     status

2021-05-06T07:35:03.000Z        mark       123
2021-04-06T07:35:03.000Z        mark       123
2021-03-03T07:35:03.000Z        mark       123
2021-02-03T07:35:03.000Z        mark       123        old_employee

2021-05-06T07:35:03.000Z        tom       4123
2021-04-06T07:35:03.000Z        tom       4123
2021-03-03T07:35:03.000Z        tom       4123

2021-02-06T07:35:03.000Z        john       512


2021-02-06T07:35:03.000Z        wood       512
2021-02-06T07:35:03.000Z        wood       512


2020-05-06T07:35:03.000Z        paul       723
2020-04-06T07:35:03.000Z        paul       723
2020-03-03T07:35:03.000Z        paul       723
2020-02-03T07:35:03.000Z        paul       723        old_employee
2020-02-03T05:35:03.000Z        paul       723        old_employee
2020-02-02T07:35:03.000Z        paul       723        old_employee
2020-02-01T07:35:03.000Z        paul       723        old_employee

2020-05-06T07:35:03.000Z        tomy       623
2020-04-06T07:35:03.000Z        tomy       623
2020-03-03T07:35:03.000Z        tomy       623
2020-02-03T07:35:03.000Z        tomy       623        old_employee
2020-02-03T05:35:03.000Z        tomy       623        old_employee
2020-02-02T07:35:03.000Z        tomy       623        old_employee
```

tried this:

```
(df.groupby('name', as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x if len(x)==1 else x.iloc[[-3]])
   .reset_index(level=0, drop=True))
```

Comment: What do you mean by  "record with oldest date" ?   If there are 4 different dates, is there criteria of how many dates to include ?   If you say by 'record' (singular), should be only one date, right ?   If more than one date, how can we decide how many dates to include ?

Answer (score 2):

You can try,

```
df.loc[df.groupby('name').cumcount() >= 3, 'status'] = 'old_employee'
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and compare by [`Series.ge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ge.html) for greater or equal:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
#if values not sorted by name and dates
#df = df.sort_values(['name','date'])

df['status'] = np.where(df.groupby('name').cumcount().ge(3), 'old_employee', '')
print (df)
                            date  name  number        status
0  2    021-05-06 07:35:03+00:00  mark     123              
1  2    021-04-06 07:35:03+00:00  mark     123              
2  2    021-03-03 07:35:03+00:00  mark     123              
3  2    021-02-03 07:35:03+00:00  mark     123  old_employee
4  2    021-05-06 07:35:03+00:00   tom    4123              
5  2    021-04-06 07:35:03+00:00   tom    4123              
6  2    021-03-03 07:35:03+00:00   tom    4123              
7  2    021-02-06 07:35:03+00:00  john     512              
8  2    021-02-06 07:35:03+00:00  wood     512              
9  2    021-02-06 07:35:03+00:00  wood     512              
10 2    020-05-06 07:35:03+00:00  paul     723              
11 2    020-04-06 07:35:03+00:00  paul     723              
12 2    020-03-03 07:35:03+00:00  paul     723              
13 2    020-02-03 07:35:03+00:00  paul     723  old_employee
14 2    020-02-03 05:35:03+00:00  paul     723  old_employee
15 2    020-02-02 07:35:03+00:00  paul     723  old_employee
16 2    020-02-01 07:35:03+00:00  paul     723  old_employee
17 2    020-05-06 07:35:03+00:00  tomy     623              
18 2    020-04-06 07:35:03+00:00  tomy     623              
19 2    020-03-03 07:35:03+00:00  tomy     623              
20 2    020-02-03 07:35:03+00:00  tomy     623  old_employee
21 2    020-02-03 05:35:03+00:00  tomy     623  old_employee
22 2    020-02-02 07:35:03+00:00  tomy     623  old_employee
```